# Let a be any odd positive integer

Tags: number-theory

Let a be any odd positive integer  and n be an integer greater than 5 .What is the smallest possible integer N such that $$a^N $$ is congruent to 1 modulo 2^n

Comment: What happens if $a = 1$? As this problem is related to modular arithmetic, have you tried applying any properties and rules?

Comment: I tried it with eulers phi function but couldn't proceed

Comment: How about $1^6 \pmod {2^6}$? If not, how about $(1+2^6)^6 \pmod {2^6}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is $\mathrm{ord}_{2^n}(a)$. We know that

$$\mathrm{ord}_{2^n}(a)|\varphi(2^n)=2^{n-1},$$

so this number must be a power of $2$. Now see if you can apply [lifting the exponent lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/) to this to find the number of times $2$ divides $a^{2^k}-1$ for a given $k$.

Comment: Actually, for $n\ge 3$, we have $\mathrm{ord}_{2^n}(a)\mid\lambda(2^n)=2^{n-2}$.

Comment: @lhf This is true, but not necessary for this solution.